# Jquery UI Tabs using ajax

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, xmlhttprequest, dom-events

I've been using bootstrap (free) theme for my CSS. Now, I created an ajax link tabs on to it. The external page/s loads normally. Now, the problem is the functions I set on each page/s is not working.

HTML:

```
<div id ='tabs'>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="ajax/content3.php">Reference Code</a></li>
    <li><a href="ajax/content4.php">search date</a></li>
    <li><a href="ajax/content5.php">Search name</a></li> 
  </ul>
</div>
```

On content3.php, the `onkeyup` event is working, but when you navigate to content4.php and content5.php the `onkeyup` event is not working. I'm using ajax to send request from the text field to another page called **getcontent#.php**. But if i run the content3.php on a separate page (not on the theme), the functions works. Can someone tell exactly what's happening?

content3.php

```
<script>
function showCustomer(str)
{
var xmlhttp;
if (str=="")
{
 document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
 return;
}
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
 {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
 xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
 xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
 if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
 {
  document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
 }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax/getcontent3.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
</script>

 <form>
<input type='text' name='searchID' id='searchID' style='width:250px' placeholder='branch name' class="form-control" onkeyup='showCustomer(this.value)'/>
</form>
```

getcontent3.php:

```
$q = $_REQUEST['q'];
$tablerpt = mysql_query(" SELECT * FROM tblpaybills LEFT JOIN tblbills ON ( tblpaybills.billsID = tblbills.billsID ) LEFT JOIN tblbranch ON ( tblpaybills.branchID = tblbranch.branchID ) WHERE tblbranch.b_Name = '".$q."' ORDER BY ABS(tblpaybills.transTime) DESC ");
```

Comment: What `onkeyup` event? i don't see that anywhere

Comment: On success of ajax, you have to bind events again such that DOM gets updated

Comment: @Ohgodwhy, i updated the post, you can see it now.

Comment: If you are loading html from **getcontent#.php**, then you have to bind events on loaded html again..

Comment: @SyedQarib, what do you mean by that? sorry, i'm just a beginner on using ajax. Could you explain it a little more simple.

Comment: to which element are you binding onkeyup event ?

Comment: is it your exact script? i think you are missing closing } for the function

Comment: @SyedQarib, im binding it on the text box.

Comment: suppose on response you are getting a textfield with 'txt' class and you want onkeyup event on that text field too then you have to declare onkeyup event for that 'txt' class again on ajax success after adding html to some container. That is what i and @dave tried telling you